# jspdf.html method does not break page (or push the content to next page)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jspdf

I am using .html() method with jsPdf to create pdf by providing html as string input to that .html();
But when the content goes to 2nd page, if there is an image at the end of first page, it gets split in 2 pages like half at the bottom of first page and half at the top of second one.
Is there any way to configure it?
I didn't use addHTML method because I am providing html string template as input. Code shown below:

```
 doc.html(templateToPrint, {
  callback (doc) {
    doc.save(`${(new Date().toLocaleTimeString())}.pdf`);
  },
  x: 15,
  y: 10
});
```

Comment: did you add any other properties like the size of the page, orientation?

Comment: Thank you for quick reply.
Yes I have added page size as below: 

const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', [297, 210]);